# Merging Audio files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, array-merge

I have an issue that I have spent forever trying to figure out and I can't get it. I want to take two audio files, and merge them into one blob so that they play at the exact same time. I don't know much about how audio works, so i'm kinda shooting in the dark. But my first idea (which I will leave the code below) was to create arrays of the decimal values of the two audio files, then add the values of a certain position together and divide by two, then push all of these new values into an array that would be turned into a blob and then played. This failed however, it played a really horrible squeaking sound.

```js
function mergeAudio(){
    var length;
    const mergedAudio = []
    //audioArray1 and audioArray2 are just arrays of the decimal values of the two audio files
    // setting the length of the merged audio
    if(audioArray1.length < audioArray2.length){
        length = audioArray1.length
    }else{
        length = audioArray2.length
    }
    //merging bytes and pushing them to a new array
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        var byte = audioArray2[i] + audioArray1[i]
        byte = byte / 2
        if(byte <= 0){
            byte = 0
        }
        mergedAudio.push(byte)   
    }
    //create Audio and play it
    const arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(mergedAudio)
    const audioBlob = new Blob(arrayBuffer);
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
    const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
    audio.play().then(function(){}).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

Like i said, this did not work, and i tried subtracting values from each byte and trying other methods to see what the outcome would be so I could figure out what I was doing wrong, but for some reason every other method I try (besides the one in the code above) leaves an error message:

> "DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

If anyone is savvy with audio or knows why I am getting this error, or if anyone knows another method to merge audio, it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Edit: I am getting my data 5 second .mp3 files and am using the code below to create an array of the data

```js
var audioArray1;
input.addEventListener('change', () =>{
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        const arrayBuffer = event.target.result
        const buffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
        const array = []
        for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++){ 
            array.push(buffer[i])
        }
        audioArray1 = array
    }
    //uses audio file that user uploaded and assigns to file reader
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
})
```

If I log the array, it shows something like this:

> (74925) [73, 68, 51, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 84, 83, 83, 69, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 3, 76, 97, 118, 102, 53, 55, 46, 53, 54, 46, 49, 48, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 251, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 110, 102, 111, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 129, 0, 1, 36, 128, 0, 5, 7, …]

Answer (score 0):

A few things to be aware of:
(1) you need to deal with PCM values, not bytes. The PCM is created by appending bytes. For example, if the format is 16-bit, one of the two bytes will be shifted 8-bits over and the two bytes are then OR'd together to form a single 16-byte value. The order of the two bytes depends on whether the format is little-endian or big-endian.
(2) Once you have the PCM, mixing the tracks together is accomplished via addition.

IDK what playback format you are using. There may be another formatting step. The only time I've played raw PCM was when using the Web-Audio API.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I sorta understand what you are saying, but I don't really know how to implement it, if i console.log the arrays, I get a long array of values ranging from 0-255, are these pcm values? because when I add the values of a certain position of each array together most of them exceed the value 255. which if I am correct, a value that exceeds 255 will result in error. Please correct me if I am wrong about anything I am very new to digital audio

Comment: Where are you getting the audio data? If it's coming by directly reading bytes from a .wav, there are things like header info to consider/avoid. And the audio data itself is going to range from -32768 to 32727 (if 16 bits), not 0-255 (8 bits). So it takes two bytes to represent one value. Sometimes the values range over what can be stored in 3 bytes or 4 bytes (known as 24-bit or 32-bit encoding) but 16-bit has been used for a long time. Also, I think the values usually have one bit dedicated to the sign (pos/neg), so the values range from - to +, not 0 to X.

Comment: The Web Audio API has javascript tools for working with audio. You might want to look for a good tutorial on it. Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Basic_concepts_behind_Web_Audio_API but it seems like you might need some more basics on how sound is represented digitally. IDK a good starter tutorial. Something like Steven A. Smith's "Scientists and Engineers Guide to Digital Signal Processing" covers things, but you'll have to wade through a bunch at the beginning to find the answers to some questions about how waves are encoded digitally.

Comment: I added an edit to the bottom of my original post for clarification. I am using .mp3 files and 8 bit encoding, so all the values range from 0-225. I am sorry for not clarifying this earlier, but now that I have, what would be the method for mixing 8 bit audio?

Comment: sorry i feel like a massive noob right now, Ive been researching digital audio basics, but this is just a problem I have had for such a long time and I haven't been able to crack it :\

Comment: If the data were truly 8-bit pcm values ranging from 0 to 255, I would first subtract 128 to get the "signed" equivalents. Then you can add the two signals. Then, add 128 to get back to unsigned. But the data you are showing really doesn't look like audio values. Are you trying to add bytes from an mp3 file without decoding it first?

Comment: Im pretty sure that the values shown there are the headers of the file, when I look further into the array the data looks like audio values.

Comment: if thats what you mean by decoding, then yes the files are not decoded. I have no clue how to decode them though so I would have to do some research on that

Comment: This might help get you started. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs